# In CRM Design, should it be mandatory to update a phone number whenever an address change is requested?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, application-design, data-quality

should it be mandatory to update a phone number whenever an address change is requested.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. On a lot of factors.

For eg, in India, if the phone type is a landline and the address changed to a different city, the area code of the phone number will be different. Hence, allowing the user to update the phone number also while updating the address makes a lot of sense.

With mobile phones, there is number portability (in most jurisdictions). However, a user could choose to not port their mobile number (rare, but can happen for a number of reasons such as provider coverage in the new area being poor or unavailable). In this case also, it makes sense to update the phone number while updating the address.

So, there is a business case for simplifying the user experience with one single update screen instead of having to update address and phone separately upon change of address, IMHO.

Comment: Interesting point for domestic landlines. How about for businesses/ organisations?

Comment: @user14163636 don't the same issues arise with businesses too, albeit on a smaller scale. For instance, at my past employer we moved from one leased office to another a few miles away. We changed our phone system at the same time and used the opportunity to change our main board number. It is infrequent. But does occur.

Mostly, this comes from Know Your Customer regulations. When you have the captive attention of the customer, it is better to get KYC update out of the way. Otherwise, the customer gets a separate notification for updating their info when it is due.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Do I award you points or something? Sorry new to this

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can click the check-mark and accept it as the answer. Cheers!